# How can I make this macro capture the lastest data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a macro recorded and its working, sort of. The problem is that its capturing the absolute cell and not the dynamic cell. Let me explain.

I have an estimating page that I copy fixtures to. In one of the cells, its going to be either an A or a B or a C... etc. When I record the macro, its capturing the absolute data (like A) when I'm on the A tab, but when I load up the B tab, the macro puts in a "A". So the routine is below. I will bold what I need to be dynamic.

```
Sub FixColumns() ' ' FixColumns Macro '

'
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 15).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Estimating1!R[3]C[-10]"
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = **"C"**
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A38"), Type:= _
        xlFillDefault
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:A38").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-45
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -14).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Estimating1!R[8]C[3]"
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = **"His Dressing"**
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A38"), Type:= _
        xlFillDefault
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:A38").Select 
    End Sub
```

So in the above macro, the "C" and "His Dressing" were captured from the C tab when I recorded the macro. so when I load up the "D" tab, it should capture the "D" and "His Bath" but it doesn't do that. It remembers when I recorded the macro when I had loaded up the C tab. So where it says `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1-"A"`, I need it to capture whatever A/B/C/D tab that I have loaded. Am I explaining this correctly? Where is says "A" or "C" or whatever in the macro, needs to be dynamic on whatever the cell actually is.

Here is a link to the file with the fixcolumns macro
[the excel file with the fixcolumn macro](http://www.filedropper.com/book4)

Answer (score 0):

I can't access the file you linked to but I'd suggest you need to look at  `Worksheet.Name` to get the name of the worksheet (tab in your parlance).

You can then use that to get a value from a column on that sheet.

On the other hand, it may just be that you need to use something like

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("A1:A38") = .Name
End With
```

It's hard to see without the original workbook to look at.

I would say though that the code that macro recorder produces for this kind of operation is usually both verbose and obtuse and that the same can often be accomplished with only a few lines of well-written VBA.

I appreciate this may seem a large step from where you are but there is a lot of help on the 'net for using Excel VBA so it will probably pay dividends to look at what you are doing and try to craft the code to suit.

Comment: can you tell me why you couldnt download the link? its just a file sharing link that I tested. as for your fix, dont know how to implement it.

Comment: @DanM probably firewall settings at work.

Comment: Not near a PC that I can open third-party code on, don't fancy accessing my office PC via TeamViewer on iPad just to try it, sorry :)